# Getting undefined value from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a page where people will be able to randomly generate some input fields, so I need to get the value of every single input and send it to my php page.

The tricky part is that I don't know how many inputs will there be in the end, and therefor I need some kind of a loop to pick all the values up. Here is what I have right now, everything seems to be ok and I do manage to get all the input fields. But for some reason values of every input field seems to be undefined, does anyone know why?

```
$(document).on('click', '#izmena', function(){
    $(function() {
        var collectionA = $('.crtezInput');
        var datas = [];
        $.each(collectionA, function(idx, obj) {
            datas.push({ 'input': $(obj).find('input').val() });
        });
        $.each(datas, function(idx, obj) { 
            crtezNaziv += obj.input +","; 
        });
        console.log(crtezNaziv);        
    });
```

```html
<div id="izmena_crteza">
    <div class="headlinea">Crtezi</div>
    <div class="crtez-form">
        <input type="text" style="width:80%; margin-bottom:10px;" class="form-control upis-style crtezInput" placeholder="Naziv" value="Glavni izgled">  
        <i title="Obrisi Arhitektu" style="margin-top: -18px;" class="fa fa-times fa-2x deleteArh"></i>
        <input type="text" style="margin-top:-20px; width:80%; margin-bottom:10px;" class="form-control upis-style crtezInput" placeholder="Razmera" value="1:100">
        <input type="text" style="width:80%; margin-bottom:10px;" class="form-control upis-style crtezInput" placeholder="Tehnika" value="Tus">
    </div>
    <div class="crtez-form">
        <input type="text" style="width:80%; margin-bottom:10px;" class="form-control upis-style crtezInput" placeholder="Naziv" value="Izgled sa strane"> 
        <i title="Obrisi Arhitektu" style="margin-top: -18px;" class="fa fa-times fa-2x deleteArh"></i>
        <input type="text" style="margin-top:-20px; width:80%; margin-bottom:10px;" class="form-control upis-style crtezInput" placeholder="Razmera" value="1:100">
        <input type="text" style="width:80%; margin-bottom:10px;" class="form-control upis-style crtezInput" placeholder="Tehnika" value="Tus">
    </div>
    <div class="crtez-form">
        <input type="text" style="width:80%; margin-bottom:10px;" class="form-control upis-style crtezInput" placeholder="Naziv" value="Presek a-b">  
        <i title="Obrisi Arhitektu" style="margin-top: -18px;" class="fa fa-times fa-2x deleteArh"></i>
        <input type="text" style="margin-top:-20px; width:80%; margin-bottom:10px;" class="form-control upis-style crtezInput" placeholder="Razmera" value="1:100">
        <input type="text" style="width:80%; margin-bottom:10px;" class="form-control upis-style crtezInput" placeholder="Tehnika" value="Tus">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the element with the ID of izmena?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting `undefined` because you're looking for `input` elements **within** your `input` elements:

```
var collectionA = $('.crtezInput');
var datas = [];
$.each(collectionA, function(idx, obj) {
    datas.push({'input': $(obj).find('input').val()});
    // Here -------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

Since you don't (and indeed *can't*) have `input` elements *within* other `input` elements, `find` doesn't find anything, and `val` returns `undefined`. (This is the **only** case where `val` returns `undefined`, btw: When the set you call it on has no elements in it. Otherwise it always returns a string, possibly a blank one.)

Here's the minimal change:

```
var collectionA = $('.crtezInput');
var datas = [];
$.each(collectionA, function(idx, obj) {
    datas.push({'input': $(obj).val()});
});
```

...but I'd probably make that a bit more direct:

```
var collectionA = $('.crtezInput');
var datas = collectionA.map(function() {
    return {input: this.value};
}).get();
```